# Last-Modified не работает

Tags: php, apache, nginx, header

не могу задать Last-Modified. Как только появляется тело документа, сразу же сбрасывается Last-Modified. Подробнее в коде:

```
<?php
$LastModified_unix = time(); // время последнего изменения страницы
$LastModified = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", $LastModified_unix);
header('Last-Modified: '. $LastModified);
exit();  //если остановить тут, то есть
echo '123';
exit();  //если остановить тут, то нету
?>
```

Не знаю куда копать. Может это вебсервер не правильно обрабатывает? тот же самый код работает на другом сервере. Стоит IspManager,(nginx+apache) а php установлен как модуль апача.

Comment: насколько я понял, обработкой запроса/ответа занимаются у вас и *nginx* и *apache*. изменения в ответ, в принципе, может внести любой из них (или оба сразу). анализируйте их конфигурации.

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо изменить в настройках Nginx **ssi on;** на **ssi off;**